# SyntaxError in PostsController#new which i dont think is syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, syntax-error

I'm developing a blog in Rub on rails. The problem is in my postsController#new. It tells me about a sytax error which i don't think its a syntax error.
[image]

And this is what is supposed to be a syntax error 
NOTE: this is a partail

```
        <%= form_for @post, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {prompt: “Choose a category” }) %><br> <-Ruby says this is my error.
  <%= f.label :title %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :title %><br>
  <%= f.label :content %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :content %><br>
  <%= f.label :image %><br>
  <%= f.file_field :image %><br>

   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

But when I debbug on earasing that line, it keeps on going to the next line and so on.

This is my controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_admin!
  def index
      @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new 
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
      flash[:success] = "El post se publicó exitosament"
      redirect_to posts_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit

  end

  def update
    if @post.update(post_params)
      flash[:success] = "Post actualizado correctamente"
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Post borrado exitosamente"
    redirect_to posts_path
  end

  private
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :category_id, :image)
    end

    def find_post
      @post = Posts.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

And my post model

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :category
 validates :title, :content, :category_id, presence: true
 has_many :line_items, inverse_of: :order
 mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

I will appreciate your help, again I dont think is a syntax error, but hope you help me find this.
Thanks developers!

Comment: `f.collection_selectç` there is an extra `c` in the last.

Comment: same error :(, but thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, prompt: 'Choose a category' %>
```

Comment: Correct! Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
<%= form_for @post, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, prompt: "Choose a category" %>
<%= f.label :title %><br>
<%= f.text_field :title %><br>
<%= f.label :content %><br>
```

Comment: Same error :/, My identation is good and im not missing no '()'